# xml parsing separating tags problem to load in webview

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, nsxmlparser

i have a xml content like this ,

```
 <bodytext>
 <p><div style='border:0px solid #d7d7d7; margin:2px 15px 2px 0px;  width:230px;      
float:left'><div style='width:230px'><img src='images/sun-1.jpg' credit='' align='left'   
alt='Man' title='Man' border='1' valign='top' hspace='0' vspace='0' style='border:1px  
solid #d7d7d7; margin:2px 2px'/></div></div>
</p>
</bodytext>
```

i need to load content in webview .is that possible to load the content inside bodytext tag directly with  parsing bodytext tag alone? or i need to parse each and every tag inside bodytext to show?
i have tried parsing bodytext alone but content was null since it couldn't read other tags ..
so is there any way to show bodytext content directly to webview?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
<items>                                                                 <bodytext>
 <p><div style='border:0px solid #d7d7d7; margin:2px 15px 2px 0px;  width:230px;      
float:left'><div style='width:230px'><img src='images/sun-1.jpg' credit='' align='left'   
alt='Man' title='Man' border='1' valign='top' hspace='0' vspace='0' style='border:1px  
solid #d7d7d7; margin:2px 2px'/></div></div>
</p>
</bodytext>
my xml will be like this format

Answer (score 1):

Store data in a string replace opening and closing tag with  or any other tag and load it

```
    [web loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: thanks i have loaded webview directly taking xml in string and used NSScanner to separate sections and finally loaded that particular section

Answer (score 0):

yeah its possible to show content. just parse bodytext tag & pass all content to webview :)

Comment: i have tried like this                                           if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"bodytext"] ) 
 {
  NSLog(@"%@",CurrentElementValue);  
 } but im getting null value and not other content within bodytext

Comment: is there any other way ?? i have coded with nsxmlparser only..is that possible to get content using that ?

Comment: check first line of your xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> this might be the problem. encode your data into that format ..

Comment: how can i change that ?how is it possible?

Comment: you are getting xmlData as response try to change encoding there :)